# How can I figure out the timestamp of the last modification of a Snowflake user via SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to get the user's creation date and last modification date via SQL.

I managed to get the `meta.created` and `meta.lastModified` via [SCIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-intro.html#user-attributes) but I would really like to get this information via SQL directly if it's possible.

Example output (`/scim/v2/Users?startIndex=200&count=1`)

```
{
  "schemas" : [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse" ],
  "Resources" : [ {
    "schemas" : [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User", "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User" ],
    "id" : "1",
    "meta" : {
      "resourceType" : "User",
      "created" : "2020-05-27T09:09:19Z",
      "lastModified" : "2020-05-27T09:09:19Z"
    },
    "userName" : "synthesis_user",
    "displayName" : "synthesis_user_display_name",
    "name" : {
      "givenName" : "synthesis_user_first_name",
      "familyName" : "synthesis_user_last_name"
    },
    "emails" : [ {
      "primary" : true,
      "value" : "synthesis.user@snowflake.com"
    } ],
    "active" : false,
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User" : {
      "defaultWarehouse" : "synthesis_warehouse",
      "defaultRole" : "synthesis_role",
      "snowflakeUserName" : "synthesis_name"
    }
  } ],
  "totalResults" : 1,
  "startIndex" : 1,
  "itemsPerPage" : 1
}
```

I managed to get the creation date via the column `CREATED_ON` on `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT.USERS':

```
SELECT CREATED_ON FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."USERS" WHERE NAME='xxxx';
```

But there is no other column there to indicate "last modification date" (the only columns that return a timestamp `TIMESTAMP_LTZ` are `CREATED_ON`, `DELETED_ON`, `BYPASS_MFA_UNTIL`, `LAST_SUCCESS_LOGIN`, `EXPIRES_AT`, `LOCKED_UNTIL_TIME`).

**So my question is there some other place where I can get when what the last change made to the user?** And by change made to the user I mean changes to the objectProperties of objectType user, or in other words the last `ALTER USER xxxx SET ...`

Comment: What type of "changes" are you interested in for a USER?  The lastModified from SCIM is coming from the SCIM side, not Snowflake.  So, the question is what is classified as a change that you are interested in the date for.  Roles granted?  Password change?  If it's just role grants, then you'd have to look for the MAX(CREATED_ON) and MAX(DELETED_ON) from the account_usage.grants_to_users view for each user to see the last time something was granted or revoked from a user.

Comment: @MikeWalton was looking for the tiemstamp of the changes of the information that is already presented at the row level on `snowflake.account_usage.users`. So in principle the timestamp of the last change of any of the objectProperties of User. Or in other words, the time of the last `ALTER USER xxxx SET ...` that actually changed something.

Answer (score 0):

To best of my knowledge, User Last_modified using SQL is not available at this point.